# Error Upon Compilation Java: "constructor LotteryTicket in class LotteryTicket cannot be applied to given types"

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to write a "LotteryTicket" program in Java, and want to test my current progress to see if it works, but the tester class will not compile properly.

Here is main code (excuse bottom classes, they are not written yet):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*;
public class LotteryTicket {
  private String nameOfBuyer;
  private int[] numberList;

  private boolean search(int val) {
    if (numberList != null && val >= 1 && val <= 50) {
      for (int number: numberList) {
        if (number == val) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  public LotteryTicket(String name) {
    name = nameOfBuyer;
    numberList = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      numberList[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(numberList); // Do not write on final form. Only for test purposes.
  }
  public double getPercentThatMatch(int[] winningNumbers) {
    return 0;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return nameOfBuyer;
  }
}
```

Here is the runner/tester:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class LotteryTicketTester {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    LotteryTicket t = new LotteryTicket();
    t.LotteryTicket(Mike);
  }
}
```

Upon compilation, the error reads:

> constructor LotteryTicket in class LotteryTicket cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: java.lang.String; found: no arguments; reason: actual and formal arguments differ in length

I assumed this meant I mistyped something, but it seems as if I did not, I checked numerous times. Again, I am very new, so I could have overlooked something very simple!

Comment: You have written a constructor that takes a String as an argument, but you are calling it with no arguments, exactly as the error message says.

Comment: You sound like my gran: "I got a popup here, what do I do?" - and it says "Do you want to save the file?"

Comment: Use `"Mike"` not `Mike`

Comment: What is `t.LotteryTicket(Mike);`? The `LotteryTicket` class has no `LotteryTicket` method, and `Mike` isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: @MightyPork Why am I getting made fun of? I just started learning Java. I thought this was a place here to help.

Comment: @NicoleI. sorry if I offended you, but it clearly told you what the error was, so I don't understand why do you post a question about it. If it just mysteriously crashed or something, that'd be a different story.

Comment: @MightyPork I am a beginner. I barley know what that "error" even meant. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the constructor in a wrong way:

```
LotteryTicket t = new LotteryTicket();
t.LotteryTicket(Mike);
```

In your code you are using a non-argument constructor, while you didn't define such (you only defined a constructor which asks for a String argument), try:

```
LotteryTicket t = new LotteryTicket("Mike");
```

Comment: Also, pay attention to the assignment you defined in your constructor: name = nameOfBuyer; you probably meant to nameOfBuyer = name;

Answer (score 0):

The comment is partly right; as the error message says, you aren't using the right arguments. You define the constructor like this:

```
public LotteryTicket(String name)
```

You're calling the constructor like this:

```
new LotteryTicket();
```

You're aren't passing it the string argument it needs. [Constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) are not the same as methods and are called when you create an object with the `new` keyword; you don't call the constructor separately like you seem to be trying to do with `t.LotteryTicket(Mike)`. Although constructors are defined similarly to methods (although they don't have a return type and can't return values), they aren't the same. You need to pass it a [string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). You can use a string literal by surrounding text with quotes like this:

```
t.LotteryTicket("Mike");
```